# C# NullReferenceException after null test

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, nullreferenceexception

Edit:  I don't believe this is a duplicate question as the question referenced explicitly states to test for null, as my code already does.  But even with this test, the exception is thrown and I don't know why.

I've written code to parse through an API and after deserializing the response, I'm populating a class with the details.  There's often null responses so null handling is a must.  However after running for over 100,000 api calls, the program crashed complaining with NullReferenceException immediately after the string is tested for null.  Whats going on here?

Condensed code:

```
    class CsvFields
    {
        public string Twitter { get; set; }
        public string Facebook { get; set; }
        public string Youtube { get; set; }
        public string Discord { get; set; }

        public void New(BeamApiChannels Channel)
        {
            this.Twitter = Channel.user.social.twitter == null ? "" : CsvClean( Channel.user.social.twitter);
            this.Facebook = Channel.user.social.facebook == null ? "" : CsvClean( Channel.user.social.facebook);
            this.Youtube = Channel.user.social.youtube == null ? "" : CsvClean( Channel.user.social.youtube);
            this.Discord = Channel.user.social.discord == null ? "" : CsvClean( Channel.user.social.discord);
        }
        public static string CsvClean(string str)
        {
            bool mustQuote = (str.Contains(",") || str.Contains("\"") || str.Contains("\r") || str.Contains("\n"));
            if (mustQuote)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (char nextChar in str)
                {
                    switch (nextChar)
                    {
                        case('"'):
                            sb.Append(nextChar);
                            sb.Append(nextChar);
                            break;
                        case ('\n'):
                            break;
                        case ('\r'):
                            break;
                        default:
                            sb.Append(nextChar);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                return sb.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: You are testing the final string but not the intermediate objects. What if Channel user or social is null?

Comment: If an intermediate object is null, does the test on the final object not also return null?

Comment: No, it fails when you try to use the following object. Suppose user = null. What does it mean Channel.NULL.social.xxxxx?. How to find social from a null? Read the duplicate, it is explained very well.

Comment: In C# 6.0 you can use the [Null propagation operator](https://davefancher.com/2014/08/14/c-6-0-null-propagation-operator/) _Channel?.user?.social?.twitter_